# Kryo: Difference between readClassAndObject/ReadObject and WriteClassAndObject/WriteObject

Tags: java, scala, kryo

I am trying to understand the following statement from the documentation:

**If the concrete class of the object is not known and the object couldbe null**:

> kryo.writeClassAndObject(output, object);
>
> Object object = kryo.readClassAndObject(input);

What does if the concrete class is not known exactly.

I am having the following code:

```
case class RawData(modelName: String,
                   sourceType: String,
                   deNormalizedVal: String,
                   normalVal: Map[String, String])

object KryoSpike extends App {


  val kryo = new Kryo()
  kryo.setRegistrationRequired(false)
  kryo.addDefaultSerializer(classOf[scala.collection.Map[_,_]], classOf[ScalaImmutableAbstractMapSerializer])
  kryo.addDefaultSerializer(classOf[scala.collection.generic.MapFactory[scala.collection.Map]], classOf[ScalaImmutableAbstractMapSerializer])
  kryo.addDefaultSerializer(classOf[RawData], classOf[ScalaProductSerializer])

  //val testin = Map("id" -> "objID", "field1" -> "field1Value")
  val testin = RawData("model1", "Json", "", Map("field1" -> "value1", "field2" -> "value2") )

  val outStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
  val output = new Output(outStream, 20480)
  kryo.writeClassAndObject(output, testin)
  output.close()


  val input = new Input(new ByteArrayInputStream(outStream.toByteArray), 4096)
  val testout = kryo.readClassAndObject(input)
  input.close()
  println(testout.toString)

}
```

When I use readClassAndObject and writeClassAndObject is works. However if I use writeObject and readObject it does not.

> Exception in thread "main" com.esotericsoftware.kryo.KryoException:
>   Class cannot be created (missing no-arg constructor):
>   com.romix.scala.serialization.kryo.ScalaProductSerializer

I just don't understand why.

earlier using the same code, Instead of using my class RawData, I used a Map and it worked like a charm with writeObject and ReadObject. Hence i am confused.

Can someone help understand it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference is as follows:

- you use `writeClassAndObject` and `readClassAndObject` when you're using a serializer that:

  - serializes a *base type*: an interface, a class that has subclasses, or - in case of Scala - a trait like [`Product`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.3/scala/Product.html),
  - **and** needs the type (i.e. the `Class` object) of the deserialized object to construct this object (without this type, it doesn't know *what* to construct),
  - example: [`ScalaProductSerializer`](https://github.com/romix/akka-kryo-serialization/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/romix/scala/serialization/kryo/ScalaProductSerializers.scala#L82)
- you use `writeObject` and `readObject` when you're using a serializer that:

  - serializes exactly one type (i.e. a class that can be instantiated; example: [`EnumSetSerializer`](https://github.com/magro/kryo-serializers/blob/master/src/main/java/de/javakaffee/kryoserializers/EnumSetSerializer.java)),
  - **or** serializes more than one type but the specific type can be somehow deduced from the serialized data (example: [`ScalaImmutableAbstractMapSerializer`](https://github.com/romix/akka-kryo-serialization/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/romix/scala/serialization/kryo/ScalaMapSerializers.scala#L107))

---

To sum this up for your specific case:

- when you deserialize your `RawData`:

  - [`ScalaProductSerializer`](https://github.com/romix/akka-kryo-serialization/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/romix/scala/serialization/kryo/ScalaProductSerializers.scala#L82) *needs* to find out the exact type of `Product` to create an instance,
  - so it uses the `typ: Class[Product]` parameter to do it,
  - as a result, only `readClassAndObject` works.
- when you deserialze a Scala immutable map ([`scala.collection.immutable.Map`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/Map.html) imported as `IMap`):

  - [`ScalaImmutableAbstractMapSerializer`](https://github.com/romix/akka-kryo-serialization/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/romix/scala/serialization/kryo/ScalaMapSerializers.scala#L107) *doesn't need* to find out the exact type - it uses `IMap.empty` to create an instance,
  - as a result, it doesn't use the `typ: Class[IMap[_, _]]` parameter,
  - as a result, both `readObject` and `readClassAndObject` work.

Comment: What a an excellent answer !! Thank you Sir !! I am sure this will help a lot of floks here.